# Folder created in Android application appears as binary file when accessed via usb

Tags: android, file, usb, directory, fedora

I created a new Folder from within my app. I did so via

```
new File(folder-path).mkdirs();
```

The folder is called "Albums" and is located in /storage/emulated/0/Pictures.
On Android there are no problems, the folder appears in several filemanagers as it should. But when I connect the phone to my computer (Fedora 21), the Folder is just a binary file with filesize ~4kb, so I cant access the files inside. I checked Permissions on the folder but I think its okay.
What can I do?
Do I have to scan the file somehow to be recognized as a folder?

Im on Android 5.0.2

Comment: Someone has an answer ? I got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

After creation (or after deletion) run:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, 
    new String[]{"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Albums/image1.jpg",
    "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Albums/image2.jpg",
    ....}
    , null, null}
```

Every file you change (create or delete) should be in the string array. Alternatively, you can restart your device every time you make a change. Note that this command does not work correctly on empty folders. It will show a 4 kb file instead, as you are seeing now.